AWS: The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC/EC2
I have been working on the full-stack course, and I am on the  AWS part, but I am having some issues with getting it to work, as the videos for it are now different from the layout for creating the instance. I have tried to use my intuition in setting up following the video, but I can not get the environment to work. I am wondering if anyone can help with this.
August 15, 2024 16:36:06 (UTC+1)
ERROR
The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the environment again.
August 15, 2024 16:36:06 (UTC+1)
ERROR
Stack named 'awseb-e-uxy3xm2t2p-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition]. 
My template has this: 
Service role
arn:aws:iam::242201283214:role/ElasticBeanstalkEC2Role
EC2 key pair - amigoscode 
EC2 instance profile - ElasticBeanstalkEC2Role

Network VPC: vpc-04c0c33bb8d0003ad
Public IP address: true
Instance subnets: subnet-09c7948e5eed2ab71,subnet-05096597f42453378,subnet-0ee8a021de0a34c5d
Database Database availability: false
Has coupled database: true
Database deletion policy: Delete
Database engine: postgres
Database engine version: 16.3
Database instance class: db.t3.micro
Database password: ******
Database storage: 20
Database subnets: subnet-09c7948e5eed2ab71,subnet-05096597f42453378,subnet-0ee8a021de0a34c5d
Database username: amigoscode

Tried changing the form, rerunning it, filling it in as best I could.
